How to demo ICMP Type 3 Code 4, Fragmentation Needed and Don't Fragment was Set
I would like to demo a situation where the MTU traffic is higher than one accepted. So, source would receive the ICMP Type 3 Code 4 as reply.
I am trying with two Linux instances running on AWS. Both are on the same network but different subnet.
Instance A has MTU of 9001. Instance B has MTU 1500.
I am trying with ping.
ping B-ip -M dont -s 9001

I would expect it to fail, but in fact it is working, it gets a reply.
How can I simulate/demo ICMP Type 3 Code 4?
I am trying with ping to avoid TCP MSS clamping. But I am open to alternatives.

You have to ping beyond B. As it is, it answers over the MTU9000 circuit which isn‘t a problem. Remember that any MTU setting applies to an interface, not the host.
You need to set up two network segments/IP subnets - one between hosts A and B with MTU 9000, and another on a second interface on B with MTU 1500. Activate routing on B. If there's actually nothing else connected to the MTU1500 subnet you need to set a static ARP entry for a dummy IP address on B (otherwise failure to ARP the destination will prevent actual packet sending attempts).
Now, when you ping dummyIP -M do -s 8972, B should return a Fragmentation Needed message.

-M do is required to set the DF flag
-s 8972 defines a maximum-sized ping payload for MTU 9000 - mind the IPv4 header of 20 octets and the ICMP header of 8 octets


Would you mind to elaborate more about ping beyond B?
